# In the sample super store,how to get customers buying only furniture and not office supplies or technology

Tags: tableau-api

In tableau for its sample super store dataset,I need to get the exclusive customers who buy only furniture and not office supplies and technology.

Want to display the exclusive customer names and their sales.

Answer (score 1):

You can put Customer on the Filter shelf and on the condition tab, use the following formula `min([Category] = "Furniture")` For boolean expressions, True > False, so MIN(condition) is true if and only if condition is true for every record. MIN() for booleans can thus be read as "every()" and MAX() can be read as "any()"

If you work with this group of customers a lot, you might want to define a set of Customers that only buy furniture, instead of a filter. There are lots of ways to think of sets, but one is just as a saved named filter.